# Как одним запросом вытащить все отчеты за месяц и связанные с ними данные?

Tags: laravel, laravel5, eloquent, laravel-5.6, laravel5.4

Контроллер:

```
        $dayReports = DayReport::all()
        ->where("day", ">=", 1)
        ->where("day", "<=", 1)
        ->where("month", ">=", 8)
        ->where("month", "<=", 8)
        ->where("year", ">=", 2018)
        ->where("year", "<=", 2018)
        ->where("username", "=", Auth::user()->name);

    foreach($dayReports as $dayReport){
        dd($dayReport->elementary);
    }
```

Модель:

```
class DayReport extends Model
{
protected $guarded = [];

public function elementary()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ElementaryReport', 'day_reports_id', 'id');
}
```

В примерах выше метод **elementary** работает только если **$dayReports** - это не массив, а всего лишь один элемент, например используя **first()** - все ОК. Как мне сделать (желательно не используя циклы - здесь будет много запросов), чтобы получить все отчеты **$dayReports**, например, за месяц и в связанной таблице **elementary_reports** взять всю информацию для всех дневных отчетов, за этот же период? P.S. В один дневной отчет может входить нескольков элементарных отчетов.

Comment: Чисто так стало интересно.. Что Вы имели ввиду под `day >= 1`, и тут же `day <= 1`..?)

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы делаете в начале `::all()`, то это возвращает коллекцию, дальше у Вас идут `where` — это уже методы коллекции.

По идее Вам нужно вот так:

```php
$dayReports = DayReport::with('elementary')
  ->where("day", ">=", 1)
  ->where("day", "<=", 1)
  ->where("month", ">=", 8)
  ->where("month", "<=", 8)
  ->where("year", ">=", 2018)
  ->where("year", "<=", 2018)
  ->where("username", "=", auth()->user()->name)
  ->get()
```